# Correct the verb between the brackets

Tags: grammaticality, past-perfect, future-continuous

> Don't call me after 7,I_____my studying(finish).

I think the answer is ***will finishing*** or I ***had finished***, but I'm not sure.

Comment: At this current version both are wrong. Basically, "will finishing" should be "will be finishing" and "had finished" is irrelevant because it's about a finished process in the past. By the way, where did you see this question?

Comment: Even once you find a verb tense to fill in the blank, you will have a run-on sentence.  Should be _"Don't call me after 7.  I ___[verb] ___ my studying."_

Answer (score 1):

*"I will be finishing"* is the right answer based on the first part of the sentence. It means don't disturb me while I'm doing something at that moment.